# Local moved to Server all nodes 404

Tags: .htaccess, 8

My homepage works perfectly fine on the live server but when I use any of the links they give me a 404 Page not Found.

I tried a couple things which was:

- Made sure .htaccess was there
- Tried a copy/paste of an .htaccess that someone provided
- Tried setting $base_url
- Tried setting Rewritebase /

Tried making sure this was in .htaccess

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I did go from an xampp local testing environment on Windows to a nginx setup on Ubuntu 14.04 so I figure it has something to do with that. I'm just not sure what to try next I've done most everything that googling brings me to.

Comment: module_rewrite is enable?

Comment: I do not see a module_rewrite in the settings at all

Comment: Are you running nginx or apache locally? Have you checked so `AllowedOverride All` is set in you webservers configuration for you local directory?

Comment: #   RewriteBase / try comment it out line

Comment: @Cyclone AllowOverride is set to none     Adi, RewriteBase was commented out, I uncommented it but I tried again still no go. Trying something else I just found we'll see what it does

Comment: Missed part of the question...Locally I'm running Apache on my Live Server its nginx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it was a bit weird how it all came together, I restarted the nginx and that didn't do anythig.

I opened the default config file for nginx and just saved it without making changes and restarted the service.

After than I went from a 404 error to a 500 error.

To fix the 500 error I changed a line in my default from this:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

To this:

```
 try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
```

I saved the config file and restarted nginx and it worked!